# Counting the number of stop words in a text

Tags: r, text-mining, stop-words

I was wondering if anyone could help me with the following problem:
I am trying to determine the number (count) of stop words in customer review texts. I am using the "quanteda" package stop words list in R.
I have tokenised the text and filtered out the stop words by using the following code:

```
stop.words <- tokens_select(corpus2.tokens, stopwords())
```

However, I am now having trouble saving these results in such a way that I can count the actual number of stopwords included in each review.

Any tipps would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show/tell us what your exact expected output is.

Comment: I would like to create a new variable with the count of stop words for every review. For example for the sentence "I've never had a better pulled pork pizza! The amount of toppings that they layered on it was astounding...bacon, corn, more pulled pork, and the sauce was delicious. I shared my pizza with 2 other people. I can't wait to go back." I would like to create a variable with the value "21", as it contains 21 stop words. Hope this clarifies? I am both new to coding and to stackoverflow. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why not simply `lengths(tokens_select(corpus2.tokens, stopwords()))` ?

Comment: Hi @StevenBeaupré, that is a lot simpler and exactly what I wanted - THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad it helped !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str_detect` from `stringr` (or `stri_detect` from `stringi`) to count the number of stopwords. str_detect will return `TRUE` or `FALSE` and these you can just count. Depending on which stopword list you have you can get different results. `stopwords("en")` from `stopwords` package will return 28. If you use `stopwords(source = "smart")` you will get a count of 61.

```
text <- "I've never had a better pulled pork pizza! The amount of toppings that they layered on it was astounding...bacon, corn, more pulled pork, and the sauce was delicious. I shared my pizza with 2 other people. I can't wait to go back."
stopwords <- stopwords::stopwords("en")

sum(stringr::str_detect(tolower(text), stopwords))
28
```